# Saved user id in Posts model, how do I render that user?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-plugins

When a user makes a post on a profile, the profile owner's user ID is saved as an integer in :poster (in the Post model). How do I find and render that user/user's information?

More information:

1. Using [Slugged gem](https://github.com/Sutto/slugged)
2. Trying to generate a feed of posts, when I call feed_item.user in my view, it directs me to the user that posted the post, but not to the user who's profile the post was made on.

Feed Item View

[image]

Feed View

[image]

Pages Controller Home Function

[image]

@postee is my feeble attempt to find the user based on the user id saved for each post. Ideally I would like to be able to link to the user who's profile the post was made on and also display information about that user in my view (e.g. the user's username). I've been tinkering for a while and am stuck, any thoughts? Thank you very much for your help and please let me know if any additional information is needed!

**EDIT**

Post Form View

```
<%= form_for @post do |f| %>
<%= f.hidden_field :name, :value => current_user.name %>
<%= f.hidden_field :poster, :value => @user.id %>
<div class="postbox">

  <div class="postfield">
    <%= f.text_area :content %>
  </div>
  <div class="postsubmit">
    <%= f.submit "Submit" %>
  </div>
</div>
```

User Controller Show Action

```
def show
  @user = User.find_by_cached_slug(params[:id])
  @posts = Post.find_all_by_poster(@user.id)
  @post = Post.new
if user_signed_in?
  @post = Post.new
  end

respond_to do |format|
  format.html # show.html.erb
  format.xml { render :xml => @user }
end
end
```

Comment: Rather than using screenshots of your code, please just paste your code into the question with four-space indentation

Comment: On Stack Overflow, you don't delete your question after it's been solved.

Comment: Can you post your solution as an answer, or else accept stephenmurdoch's answer if you used it? I'm sure many other people would like to know how to solve this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ultimately, I decided to do it in a non-railsy way, just to get the functionality working. Though I suspect that if you can somehow tie the user id in :poster to a new model with (has many, belongs to, etc...) relationships set up, it would work much better that way. (I believe that this is what stephenmurdoch's answer was attempting, there was just a problem with :user_id already being tied to the posting user.)

I saved more user information when each post was made, and then rendered the profile post receiver's information for each feed item. Also because user's have unique URLs based on cached_slug, I was able to use <%= link_to feed_item.postername, feed_item.postercachedslug %> to create a link to the profile the post was made on.

Post Form View

```
<%= form_for @post do |f| %>
<%= f.hidden_field :name, :value => current_user.name %>
<%= f.hidden_field :poster, :value => @user.id %>
<%= f.hidden_field :postername, :value => @user.name %>
<%= f.hidden_field :posterusername, :value => current_user.username %>
<%= f.hidden_field :postercachedslug, :value => @user.cached_slug %>
<div class="postbox">

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.text_area :content %>
  </div>
  <div class="submit">
    <%= f.submit "Submit" %>
  </div>
</div>
```

Feed Item view

```
<div class="profilepic">
<% if feed_item.user.profile_file_name == nil %>
<%= link_to image_tag("thumb.jpeg"), feed_item.user %>
<% else %>
  <%= link_to image_tag(feed_item.user.profile.url(:thumb)), feed_item.user %>
 <% end %>
</div>
<span class='feeditem'>
    <div class='row1'>
      <strong>
        <span class="user"><%= link_to feed_item.name, feed_item.user %> </span>
      </strong>
      <%= image_tag("arrow.png") %>
      <span class="name"><%= link_to feed_item.postername, feed_item.postercachedslug %></span>
    </div>
  <div class='row2'>
    <span class="content"><%= feed_item.content %></span>
  </div>
  <div class='row3'>
<span class="timestamp">
  <%= time_ago_in_words(feed_item.created_at) %> ago.
</span>
    <% if current_user?(feed_item.user) %>
        <%= link_to "delete", feed_item, :method => :delete,
                    :confirm => "You sure?" %>
    <% end %>
  </div>
  </span>
```

Answer (score 4):

your method is slightly odd, in that you use the attribute `:poster` instead of `:user_id` which is the rails convention

Anyway, try sticking something like this in your view

```
@post.poster.email # to return the email address of your user
```

The code above depends on your user model having an `:email` attribute
change email for whatever attribute you wish to return, whether it be username etc

Do you have a relationship between posts and users specified in your model? i.e. `belongs_to :user`

IS there a reason why you are not using the conventional of :model_name_id for your associated record?

Comment: hey stephen, thanks for the suggestion! the method is odd because :user_id contains the user id of the user that made the post, while :poster contains the user id of the user who's profile was posted on. in attempting your suggestion, i dont use an @post instance variable, but i tried post.poster.email and feed_item.poster.email, neither worked (undefined method `email' for 9:Fixnum) but w/o the .email added on the end, both render the correct :poster id. And I have relationships set up, Post belongs_to :user, User has_many :posts. Anything else I can try? Thanks!

Comment: @ahuang7: Please show us how you're defining the `poster` method.

Comment: hey ryan, i posted the code above in an edit. i appreciate your help and will remember to paste the code, rather than screenshots in the future! as a side question, if there's a better way to refactor my code, i'd be very intrigued to learn it as a rails student.